# Error when starting newrelic-daemon on freebsd 8.1

Tags: newrelic

I have installed the newrelic-deamon on our production environment but its won't start.

I get this error message when I tries to start it ( as root )

```
/libexec/ld-elf.so.1: Shared object "libz.so.4" not found, required by "newrelic-daemon"
```

What to do to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the libz problem create a symlink to that file from your currently installed libz version. It is supposed to be ABI-compatible.

Explanation: The PHP agent is compiled on FreeBSD 7.0. That is to ensure maximum FreeBSD penetration, because in theory, anything compiled on FreeBSD 7 should work out of the box on FreeBSD 8. Except of course, it doesn't, because there are countless ways of upgrading a FreeBSD system.

If you have any further issues, please contact us at support@newrelic.com